# Styling images to look the same with out photoshop

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, image

I apologize for the title I'm not sure how to explain what I'm trying to do in one sentence. I'm working on a WordPress site, and I need to make a bunch of images look like the background image in the "Plastic Surgery" section of this page https://rinklefreeps.wpengine.com/

I could go through and edit them all with photoshop but I feel like if there is a way to code this out it would be a lot better because then if I ever need to change any of them all I need to do is put the image in and it will already look right. I also need to be able to put alt tags on them.

So I guess what im saying is I need to recreate the "Plastic Surgery" section with a background image that I can put an alt tag on. I'm jsut not quite sure where to start with this any help would be great. Thanks Guys!

Comment: You mean with a white-ish overlay that fades the img? or the slanted white cover thing on the left side?

Comment: The slanted part. If I could swap out the image and still have that slant with out having to manipulate the image in PS that would be ideal. There's like 50 images I need to add to other sections of the site with the same exact styling.

Comment: I was working on it and did the overlay but can take that off. Like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLjJzW

Comment: Yeah exactly like that! The issue though is that I need the image to act as a background for a section of content and I need the test to be in front of the image but I also need to be able to put an alt tag on the image for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap the `img` in an element, you can use the `::before/::after` pseudo classes to make a semi-opaque overlay using `rgba()` and a slanted, solid overlay using positioning with a `background-color` and `transform: rotate()` to create the slant.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
.imgContainer {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.imgContainer::after, .imgContainer::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.imgContainer::after {
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.imgContainer::before {
  height: 200%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-40%,-50%) rotate(15deg);
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  width: 80%; height: 80%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
  z-index: 1;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer">
  <img src="http://cdn.thedailybeast.com/content/dailybeast/articles/2015/03/31/neil-degrasse-tyson-defends-scientology-and-the-bush-administration-s-science-record/jcr:content/image.img.2000.jpg/1432067001553.cached.jpg" alt="alt">
  <div class="text">
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a great idea! I'm still kind of new to psuedo classes so they're not usually the first thing to pop into my head. I guess the biggest problem I'm having though is that I need the text to be in front of the image.

Comment: @ajwerth you didn't mention the text in your post, so I didn't include it. Added it. And there is an `alt` attribute on the image.

Comment: @ajwerth sweet, you bet :)